# (Kotlin) Making canvas inside ConstraintLayout scrollable

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, scrollview, scrollable

At some point in my application, there's a canvas being added to a ConstraintLayout. This canvas can be bigger than said ConstraintLayout, so I need it to be scrollable.

After reading through some questions regarding seemingly similar problem, the best (I think) I've come up with is the following hirearchy:

**1) Unnamed ConstraintLayout** - the main ConstraintLayout of my .xml file. Inside it we have...

**2) ConstraintLayout named ScreenContainer** - it's still pretty normal. Inside it there's...

**3) Unnamed NestedScrollView** - which at last contains...

**4) ConstraintLayout named Screen** - there's where my canvas is being added programatically.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I've got no idea why.

Here's the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ScreenContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/LengthDisplay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/Screen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

         ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your custom `View` code

Comment: You mean the code that adds canvas to Screen (ConstraintLayout)? In this case: `Screen.addView(Canvass (this))`

Comment: ViewGroup#addView() method takes View as a parameter, not Canvas, so post the code of that custom View you want to add

Comment: OK. Here it is then: https://pastebin.com/BStt37qR

Comment: Do not use match_parent inside ConstraintLayout it does absolutely nothing; you should be using 0dp instead inside constraint layout. Also nested scroll view should be wrap_content I think.

Comment: Well, after setting all ConstraintLayouts' (except the parent CL of the whole layout) width and height to 0dp and NestedScrollView's to wrap_content, the canvas won't even show on the screen, so I don't think it's the case :/